# SQL SUM and Average Sale by Years

Tags: sql

I have a table where monthly sales are recorded. See image for a sample of the table.[image]

So this data is partial, I have months 1-12 for every year since 2000. What I would normally do is query total sales for any one year like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_sales) as TotalSalesYear FROM sales_report WHERE year =  '2008'
```

What I want to do here is determine the highest year in sales and the average sales per year since 2000. So I need to do a SUM per year, and determine which year is the highest. Then, once I have the SUM for each year, I can come with an average of sales per year.

I'm just not sure how to query this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should *always* tag your DBMS when asking SQL questions. SQL dialects differ. What works for one DBMS doesn't necessarily work for another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by year in order to get a result record per year. Order it by the sales sum descending and limit your results to 1 row, so you get the year with the maximum sales sum.

Additionally we use the analytic version of `AVG` to get the avarage over all sums with each year record (of which we show only one at last). Remove the last line (i.e. the fetch only clause) from the query to see how it works.

```
select 
  year, 
  sum(total_sales) as sum_of_year, 
  avg(sum(total_sales)) over () as avg_sum
from sales_report 
group by year
order by sum(total_sales) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fee30/5

This is standard SQL but doesn't work in every DBMS. Some DBMS are more standard compliant, others are less. Some use `TOP` or `LIMIT` or something else to get the top row only. And some don't even feature analytic functions.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. That works (kind of). I'd like to modify as follow. As you can see in my table above, I have months for each year. Your query works great for calendar year (i.e. January to December). I need to go by fiscal year. Our fiscal actually goes from July to June (example: July 2010 to June 2011. So same idea, except I need to define the "year" fromJune to July for each year, Thank you.

Comment: So the first six months of, say, 2011 belong to the fiscal year 2010. That means for the months 1 to 6 we have to subtract 1 from the year, that's all: Replace `year` with `year - case when month <= 6 then 1 else 0 end` in the query. Some DBMS even let you create functions, so you could write a function `fiscal_year(year, month)` to get this more readable. Or you could have a computed column for the fiscal year in the table, if your DBMS offers that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the second part of your question. This will compute the average of sum of sales over all years:

```
SELECT avg(sum_sales) 
FROM (
      SELECT year as year, sum(total_sales) as sum_sales     
        FROM sales 
    GROUP BY year
) AS T;
```

For getting the year with the highest sales, you could extend this using order by and limit as follows:

```
SELECT year, sum_sales   
  FROM ( 
       SELECT year as year, sum(total_sales) as sum_sales            
         FROM sales        
        GROUP BY year) AS T 
 ORDER BY sum_sales desc 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: so just to confirm the average query, this will still get a SUM by year first, and then averages? Example, the earliest year is 1992 all the way to 2015. This will first take the SUM for 1992, 1993, all the way to 2015. It then SUMS all 23 years and divides by 23 to get the average yearly sales since 1992?

Comment: yes, exactly. It first gets the sum by years, and then averages over all those sums. I like Thorsten's solution also, which gets the results in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select rank()over (  order by total_sale) rnk,
 year, total_sale, avg_sale
    from (select year, 
sum(total_sales) total_sale,
 avg(total_sales) avg_sale
 from sales_report group by year)
```

This query provides the rank for every year. rnk=1 is the year with highest sales. By saying rnk=1, you can get the total sales and average sales for the year with highest sales. Hope this helps!